# Euler formula and $\sin^3$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Using the formula:

> $$e^{i\omega t} = \cos {\omega t} + i\sin{\omega t}$$

I would like to prove that:

> $$\sin^3\;x =  -\frac{\sin{3x} - 3\sin{x}}{4} $$

However I haven't found any approach to this question. Just converting the first formula to $\sin^3$ doesn't seem to help as I'm still getting $\cos^3$ on the other side. Can anyone help me to guide me on the right way?

Comment: Try cubing the first formula as it is and taking the imaginary part on each side. You may also need to use $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$ Taking the real part gives the corresponding formula for cos.

Comment: @Mark: you should make that an answer!

Comment: I was trying to give a hint rather than an answer, because I reckon you get more value working through the calculation at least once in your life.

Answer (score 10):

$$
\sin^3 x = \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^3
= \frac{e^{i3x}-3e^{ix}+3e^{-ix}-e^{-i3x}}{-8i}
$$

$$
= -\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{e^{i3x}-e^{-i3x}}{2i}\right)
+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)
= -\frac{\sin 3x - 3\sin x}{4}
$$

Comment: +1 for showing that no ingenunity is required; the equation $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$ is really a ["proof machine"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) for most trigonometric identities that can be carried out mechanically.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR : Agreed, I think this way is the most straightforward.

Comment: another answer gets bumped, and yours gets upvoted :-)

Comment: But it seems CuStud never came back to look at the answers...

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know de Moivre's Theorem, in fact it is implicit in the first formula.

Try $(e^{i\omega t})^3 = (\cos {\omega t} + i\sin{\omega t})^3$.

But you also have

$$ (e^{i\omega t})^3 = e^{i3\omega t} = \cos {3\omega t} + i\sin{3\omega t}$$

using the first formula with $3\omega t$ instead of $\omega t$.

Equate the two, take real and imaginary parts, and use $1 - \cos^2 x = \sin^2 x$ to get everything in terms of the $\sin$ function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it:

By de Moivre's theorem, you should know that

$(\cos 3x + i \sin 3x) = (\cos x + i \sin x)^3$.

Expand the term on the right hand side using the binomial theorem, viz
$(\cos 3x + i \sin 3x) = \cos^3 x +3i\cos^2 x \sin x - 3\sin^2 x \cos x - i \sin^3 x.$

So equating imaginary parts and you should get

$\sin^3 x = 3\cos^2 x \sin x - \sin 3x$.

Then you can use the fact that $1 - \cos^2 x = \sin^2 x$ which gives:

$\sin^3 x = (3 - 3\sin^2 x)\sin x - \sin3x$,  hence

$4\sin^3 x = 3\sin x - \sin 3x$

which is what you want.

Comment: But you ignored the "Using" clause in the question!  See my answer...